# How to get service of concrete Module in JPMS?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have a dynamically created layer that has about 25 modules. About 7-10 modules can provide `com.foo.Bar` service. I need to get a service of concrete module - I have a reference to `Module`. Could anyone say how to do it? Details:

```
public com.foo.Bar getService(Module module) {
   //solution one - get all services on this layer, after iterate them and check 
   //if some service belongs to `module`. But maybe there are better solutions?
   ?
}
```

Comment: Maybe module.getDescriptor().provides()?

Comment: `ServiceLoader.load(module.getLayer(), com.foo.Bar).stream().filter(s -> s.type().getModule() == module).findAny()`